# Visual studio 2015 Logitec Setpoint software keystroke with mouse button

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

I've just installed the Setpoint logitech software on a new PC with windows server 2012. I've assigned to one of the buttons of my mouse the keystroke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, which supposed to switch between open files on visual studio but it is not working!

If i press on the button on chrome, it switch tabs, but on VS it does nothing... 
If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> myself in VS the file will be switched... 
I've used this keystrokes many times in diffrent PC's with diffrent enviroment on visual studio 2013 and it worked fine...

My mouse is M705 marathon mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending few days looking for a solution - 
It was quite simple, I'll post it here:

VS ignoring Setpoint software unless it is on "run as administrator".

To fix this:
Right click Setpoint, exit the program.

Search for Setpoint in the start menu, for me it was here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Logitech\Mouse and Keyboard

Go to properties, compatability tab, mark 'run as administrator'. 
Now press on the shortcut and that's it.

Comment: I found this to be the solution for me as well. I also found that the media hotkeys (e.g. play/pause) on my logitech keyboard were getting blocked by VS 2015 running in admin mode. Oddly enough, exiting SetPoint altogether unblocked the hotkeys.

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution! BTW, for me the executable was here: `C:\Program Files\Logitech\SetPointP\SetPoint.exe`.

Comment: adding "setpoint hotkeys not working" for keyword reasons...i didn't even realize it was only visual studio where they weren't working because that was the only thing I was testing with.